# Can a half-fiend be a patron for a warlock?

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock

I'm about to start running a campaign and one of my players wants to start as a wizard and multiclass warlock as well. I had already started creating a fairly powerful half-fiend (originally to be a big enemy much later on). I know that fiends can be patrons, but would a half-fiend be powerful enough to offer up a deal like that to my player?

Answer (score 21):

#### You’re the DM. It’s your world.

It’s totally up to you to determine if such a being is a suitable warlock patron. It’s your world. As the DM, you are responsible for building it.

That said, the guidance in the PHB about fiend patrons says:

> Fiends powerful enough to forge a pact include demon lords such as Demogorgon, Orcus, Fraz’Urb-luu, and Baphomet; archdevils such as Asmodeus, Dispater, Mephistopheles, and Belial; pit fiends and balors that are especially mighty; and ultroloths and other lords of the yugoloths.

It’s up to you if this half fiend is powerful enough *in your mind* to make a pact. You can follow the guidance here, but you don’t have to. The *Dungeon Master’s Guide* says:

> Every DM is the creator of his or her own campaign world. Whether you invent a world, adapt a world from a favorite movie or novel, or use a published setting for the D&D game, you make that world your own over the course of a campaign.

Comment: For added precedent: Vecna was a human. He then became a rich and is now a demigod/full-blown-god depending on setting. He's got more than enough power to act as a patron should a DM choose so, and he started off vanilla mortal. The half fiend has both fiendish blood and DM fiat on their side!

Comment: I don't know whether _MToF_ addresses this in its Chapter 1, but if it did, that might allow you to provide more detail and support to your answer.

Answer (score 5):

The answer "You're the DM, you can do what you want" is usually pretty valid, but someone already said that here so I'm going to take another approach. Let's talk about other entities you can form a pact with, and you can decide if your half-fiend resembles them.
Any suitably powerful being could theoretically forge a pact with somebody, depending on if the all-powerful entity known as the Dungeon Master decrees it to be possible. Let's take a look at the main half-fiend monster that came to my mind when I read this - a cambion.

The 5th edition monster manual doesn't go into too much detail on the actual magical prowess of cambions, but it does mention:

> ***Pawns of the Mighty.*** A cambion forced to serve its fiendish parent does so out of admiration and dread, but also with the expectation that it will one day rise to a place of prominence.

I'm assuming this means that a cambion could rise in the hierarchy of either devils or demons, whichever its parent might be - and this is further supported by another passage in that same section.

> In the Abyss, a cambion carries only as much authority as it can muster through sheer strength and force of will.

Granted, the cambion in the MM is CR 5 - probably a lot weaker than the being you're talking about. But I think there's enough in the actual books to justify even a half-fiend becoming powerful enough to enter into a pact. And hey, even CR 5 might be enough to be a patron - you can enter into a *Pact of the Archfey* with a hag, after all. The longer these sorts of beings are around, the more power they tend to have, so I'd assume that a particularly old half-fiend would probably have enough magical income to play the patron game. I hope this helps!

Comment: Regarding CR and patrons, one of the suggested patrons for a Celestial warlock is a unicorn, which only comes in at CR 5. (The ancient hags suggested for the Archfey are presumably higher)

Comment: Oh, and Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Oh, that's a good point! I totally forgot about unicorns, thanks for the catch - AND the welcome!

Answer (score 4):

Canonically, a half fiend can be a patron.

In [*The Brimstone Angels* book series](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Brimstone_Angels_series), cambion (ie. a half fiend) [Lorcan](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Lorcan), is patron of the main protagonist, tiefling [Farideh](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Farideh). Lorcan actually collected warlocks, and was a patron of several.

The fiend patron was just the one who made the pact and offered access to power of one of the Nine Hells. In the books he was presented as the one who taught new skills (which in an RPG game would have equaled leveling up) but was not otherwise necessary for the Warlock powers to work.

If it wasn't directly said, it was at least implied that what the patron needs is connections, ie. permission to make the Warlock pacts. How common it would be, that's a question. *Everyone* (except Asmodeus) in the Nine Hells is serving someone else, and doesn't really have freedom to do as they please, except within bounds given by their master.

Now the book series takes place in, and actually ends at the end of "4th edition era", but it is strongly implied that Farideh kept her powers even after that [*Second Sundering*](https://forgottenrealms.fandom.com/wiki/Second_Sundering) cataclysm, so this can be considered valid for 5th edition as well.

PS. I rather enjoyed the book series, it gave me a desire to play a warlock immediately.

(TBA, quotes from the books.)